# Prove some inequality using Jensen's inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, examples-counterexamples, jensen-inequality

How do I prove this using Jensen's inequality?

$$\biggl|\prod_{i=1}^n x_{i}\biggl|^p \le {n^{p-1}}\sum_{i=1}^n |x_{i}|^p$$

I've tried log on both sides but I couldn't find a common expression.

on the right side I did:  $$log( E(n|x|)^p) = log({n^{p-1}}\sum_{i=1}^n |x_{i}|^p)$$
and on the left side:  $$ E(log(|x|)^{np}) = log\bigg(\bigg|\prod_{i=1}^n x_{i}\bigg|\bigg)^p$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wrong.

Try $p=1$, $n=2$ and $a=b=3$.

We need to prove that $6\geq9$, which is not so true.